# nodejs express mongoose - trying to get length of list as a virtual parameter in a model as a response

Tags: node.js, api, express, mongoose

Using virtual parameter in a model, how can I calculate the length of a list in one of the parameters of a model, and sent back as a response on an api call?

.... SERVER file: server.js ....

```
//GET an ARRAY of users (and total counter of users) data via api
    app.get('/api/v1/users', (req,res) => {
        Userslist.find((err, userslists) => {
            if (err){
                res.send(err);
            }else{
                res.send(userslists);
            }
        });
    });
```

.... MODEL file: Users.js ....

```
var userslistSchema = new Schema({
    items: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ArrayOfUser'},
},{
    toObject: {virtuals: true}, toJSON: {virtuals: true}
})

userslistSchema.virtual('total')
    .get(function() {return this.items.length})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Userslist', userslistSchema)
```

Comment: I'm getting..."TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: Also, it not creating the collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues: If **items** is supposed to be an **Array** is should be defined as below.

```
var userslistSchema = new Schema({
    items: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ArrayOfUser'}],
},{
    toObject: {virtuals: true}, toJSON: {virtuals: true}
})
```

Second while defining virtual **total**. The case when no **items** are present is not handled. Handle it appropriately a sample code is below. P.S. - It is just a sample for understanding(it can  be handled better)

```
userslistSchema.virtual('total')
    .get(function() {return (this.items && this.items.length) ? this.items.length : 0})
```